# how can i output all the rows from my database?

Tags: php, html, sql

I want to output all of the rows from my sql database into a table but I can only get 1 row to output. 
this is my code so far:

```
<?php

$users = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM people");
if (mysqli_num_rows($users) == 0) {

echo ('No matches in the database');

}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($users)){
    $name = $row['name'];
    $postcode = $row['postcode'];
    $email = $row ['email'];
}
?>

<table>
<tr><td>Name:</td></tr>
<tr><td><?php echo ($name) ?></td></tr>

<tr><td>postcode:</td></tr>
<tr><td><?php echo ($postcode) ?></td></tr>

<tr><td>email:</td></tr>
<tr><td><?php echo ($email) ?></td></tr>
</table>
```

This only outputs one, how can I output all the rows?

Comment: Put the HTML table in the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the table inside a loop like so:

```
<?php

$users = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM people");
if (mysqli_num_rows($users) == 0) {

echo ('No matches in the database');

}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($users)){
    $name = $row['name'];
    $postcode = $row['postcode'];
    $email = $row ['email'];
```

*remove '}' from here*

```
?>

<table>
<tr><td>Name:</td></tr>
<tr><td><?php echo ($name) ?></td></tr>

<tr><td>postcode:</td></tr>
<tr><td><?php echo ($postcode) ?></td></tr>

<tr><td>email:</td></tr>
<tr><td><?php echo ($email) ?></td></tr>
</table>

<?php 
}
?>
```

*And add it back in after the table to create the loop*

Comment: don't just repost the entire code with a few minor changes without highlighting WHERE you made the changes. but otherwise, 100% correct.

Comment: there, now it's edited. thought it was fairly straight forward to see the changes on that one anyway

Comment: happy now, @Fred-ii- ? caps lock CAN BE A PAIN

Comment: You might have thought that, but keep in mind the number of newbies who might be viewing this kind of code for the first time. A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.